# Addressof syntax without delegate

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, delegates

I am using this delegate to invoke my methode:

```
Private Delegate Sub NoArgDelegate()



Dim dl As New NoArgDelegate(AddressOf MyLoad)
Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(dl, Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle)


Private Sub MyLoad()
End Sub
```

Is there any way to do this without my NoArgDelegate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using WPF, the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate should be available.  So you don't need to define your own delegate.

Comment: Thanks. Can you make an example in VB.Net? I just found that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have been answering a different aspect of your question.  I answered your question on not using your `NoArgDelegate` delegate.  You should be able to use `Action` in its place.  But regarding your question in the title, not having to specify a delegate type when using an existing method, that is not possible.  The method name alone is considered a method group since there could be many different overloads.  You _must_ specify which delegate should be used so the compiler knows what to do with it.

Comment: Is there any way though Lambda Expressions?

Comment: @gold: Even with a lambda, it will be required.  The `[Begin]Invoke()` call takes any _specific_ delegate.  The lambda's specific type cannot be inferred here just like the method group.  You'll need to use a delegate somewhere either way.  You can however replace your methods using delegates, that way you don't have to use `AddressOf` but that would be an ugly solution and you could no longer do overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use [`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) or [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) instead of creating your own delegate :) However, I assume that what you're really asking about is the need to explicitly specify the delegate type when you call `BeginInvoke`.

The problem is that `Dispatcher.BeingInvoke` takes *any* delegate, so the compiler won't know what to convert `AddressOf MyLoad` to.

You could add your own extension method though which has a parameter of `Action` - I believe that would let you call it without explicitly specifying the delegate in the calling code.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Just wonder how it could look after googling. Can you make an example in VB.Net? I just found that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @goldengel: I don't have the time to do it right now. I suggest you have a go yourself, and then edit your question with how far you've got...